# Rails I18n doesn't work with asset pipeline templates in Rails 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets, rails-i18n

I need to localize an app, so I created a file for Spanish translations, but the `config/locales/es.yml` file doesn't seem to be properly loading, or maybe it loads after my templates are evaluated.

First a little context, I'm using the [handlebars_assets](https://github.com/leshill/handlebars_assets) and [haml_assets](https://github.com/carezone/haml_assets) gems. The latter allows to use the `ActionView` helpers within the templates in the asset pipeline and it also has access to the application classes, so one could write templates like:

```
.some_div
  = SomeModel.model_name.human
```

And it works, except that it's returning the fallback name of the model. If I make these kinds of translations in a view though (instead of `.hbs.haml` template) I get the proper translated string. This is also true if I execute the translation methods in the rails console.

Following the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) I created the following initializer:

```
I18n.default_local = :es
```

Which is working properly if I consider that translating in views renders the expected output. My application is mostly living on the client side, so I really don't use Rails' views, it's a single page application managed with the help of Backbone. All the UI lives in templates that get rendered through the asset pipeline. So my question is, has anyone managed to make I18n work with this setup?